# How can I return a post that has only 2 comments associated with it using aggregate?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregate

I'm trying to figure out a way to aggregate all posts that have 2 comments associated with them.
Given the fake data below, only post 1 should return because comments 10 and 11 have post uuid 1 associated with them.
Posts

```
{
    uuid: 1,
    title: "Post 1",
}
{
    uuid: 2,
    title: "Post 2",
}
{
    uuid: 3,
    title: "Post 3",
}
```

Comments

```
{
    uuid: 10,
    postUuid: "1",
}
{
    uuid: 11,
    postUuid: "1",
}
{
    uuid: 12,
    postUuid: "2",
}
```

Here's the current aggregation code I'm using with Mongoose to return posts and comments, but I'm not sure how to add a filter to only return posts with 2 comments.

```
PostSchema.aggregate([
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: “comments”,
          as: "comments",
        },
      },
      {
        $unwind: {
          path: "$comments”,
          preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: false,
        },
      },
      {
        $match: {
          uuid: “comments.postUuid",
        },
      },
    ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Demo - https://mongoplayground.net/p/G2oynDBTrQW

```
db.post.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "comments",
      localField: "uuid",
      foreignField: "postUuid",
      as: "comments",
    }, 
  },
  { $match: { "comments.1": { $exists: true } }} // check if the index 1 is available for the array - array length is 2
])
```